# How to avoid "AttributeError: cls not available in session-scoped context" using request.cls and scope="session"?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, fixtures

I have next construction:
**1. BaseClass with fixture**

```
class BaseClass:
    instance = None

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, request):
        request.cls.instance = AnotherClass()
        request.cls.instance.open_session()

        yield

        self.instance.close_session()
```

**2. TestClass with a test**

```
class TestClass(BaseClass):
    def awesome_test(self):
        value = self.instance.get_value("parameter")
        assert value == "correct result"
```

**Question:** if I want to save this kind of construction with reusing an instance of the class in the actual test, parameter scope="session" and yield in the fixtures, how can I avoid/solve an error "AttributeError: cls not available in session-scoped context" (if possible)?

I tried:

1. Creating 2 fixtures: one for setup and creating instances of class and second for yield and close connection

Comment: Either use a class scope, or save your data elsewhere - a session based fixture cannot have class.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I understand that session based fixture can't have a class. How usually accepted in the industry to use a lot of test classes and only one "setup_and_teardown"  fixture for all of them IF I also need to create instances in that fixture as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to have session-scoped fixture as a method in a class - this creates the impression that it have access to the class or a class instance, which it has not.

Instead, write the session-scoped fixture outside the class and `yield` the created object. Pytest will cache the object and pass it to any test that requires it:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def instance():
    inst = AnotherClass()
    inst.open_session()
    
    yield inst

    inst.close_session()

class TestClass:
    def awesome_test(self, instance):
        value = instance.get_value("parameter")
        assert value == "correct result"
```

This also makes the base class obsolete.